# Detect when bottom of list is on screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

We are using Angularjs ui accordian to display a list of items, however, what we would like to achieve is, that for example, 50 items are displayed at first.

Then scrolling down, when the 50th item is in view on the sreen, go away, get the next 50 and append to the list.

surly this possible? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated as we are struggling to find any samples to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

The below link answers the question
http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

infinit scrolling
http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html